# Getting a Rails app to trigger AppleScript on a server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, applescript

This may seem like a bizarre question, but I'm wondering if there's a preferred or established method of getting a Rails app to perform an AppleScript on a server?

Until now I've been getting the app to send an email to the server and the script responds to that, but it feels less than robust.

Any ideas? Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always possible to create a shell script and execute it via `ssh`, but IMHO, guarantee to run a shell script and retrieve the shell execution result can be a nightmare.

There are several gems to execute AppleScript, so, if I need to robustly execute AppleScript, I will create a server written in Rails on the remote side and kick the server with REST.

And, Of course, I will **never** pass the script via the REST call for security reason. I will create procedures one by one.

Comment: Any suggestions for the gems? The AppleScript will be remote, not local.

Comment: I don't know remote capable gems. As I remember, AppleScript was designed as remote capable, but not used that way. Also think about security concerns. As I described above, I suggest to setup client-server to do that robustly.

Answer (score 0):

```
puts `/path/to/your/script`
```

That will only work locally. If you want to do something remotely you would need to setup ssh and make your calls via ssh calls.